# Can't Build OpenJFX with Eclipse OpenJ9+181

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, openj9

The new [Eclipse J9 jvm](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk9-openj9) does not come bundled with JavaFX, so I have tried to build OpenJFX but have failed.

I believe I have followed all the build instructions on the [OpenJFX website](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX#BuildingOpenJFX-GettingtheSources).  I have Gradle 3.1, Ant, and the required libraries installed.  I'm running Fedora 26.

J9 appears to be failing with some kind of segmentation fault.  Here is the error message I'm getting after I run `gradle` in the OpenJFX mercurial repository.

```
[_@localhost rt]$ gradle
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod (file:/usr/local/share/gradle-3.1/lib/gradle-base-services-3.1.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.getPackages()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Unhandled exception
Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00040000
J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000004 Signal_Number=0000000b Error_Value=00000000 Signal_Code=00000001
Handler1=00007F822A5BF730 Handler2=00007F82297A4D30 InaccessibleAddress=0000000000000008
RDI=00000000013AFA00 RSI=0000000000000000 RAX=0000000000000004 RBX=00007F822400FDA0
RCX=0000000000000011 RDX=0000000000000000 R8=00007F822400FDA0 R9=0000000000000000
R10=00007F822493EDD0 R11=00007F822BCC1610 R12=00000000013AFA00 R13=00007F822400FDA0
R14=00000000013AFA00 R15=00007F822B4E8190
RIP=00007F822A5EBA20 GS=0000 FS=0000 RSP=00007F822B4E8150
EFlags=0000000000010246 CS=0033 RBP=0000000000000000 ERR=0000000000000004
TRAPNO=000000000000000E OLDMASK=0000000000000000 CR2=0000000000000008
xmm0 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
xmm1 726f6674616c502f (f: 1634488320.000000, d: 1.675017e+243)
xmm2 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
xmm3 0000ff0000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 1.385239e-309)
xmm4 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
xmm5 3bbcc86800000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 6.095003e-21)
xmm6 402bd9b2780ad4ad (f: 2013975680.000000, d: 1.392519e+01)
xmm7 402bd9b2780ad4ad (f: 2013975680.000000, d: 1.392519e+01)
xmm8 3ff0000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 1.000000e+00)
xmm9 402bd9b1c3a0f13b (f: 3282104576.000000, d: 1.392518e+01)
xmm10 3fee11aacd651245 (f: 3445953024.000000, d: 9.396566e-01)
xmm11 3cc7800000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 6.522560e-16)
xmm12 bc40000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: -1.734723e-18)
xmm13 402bb9d3beb8c600 (f: 3199780352.000000, d: 1.386294e+01)
xmm14 3bfc4721da1f8579 (f: 3659498752.000000, d: 9.580912e-20)
xmm15 402bb9d3beb8c600 (f: 3199780352.000000, d: 1.386294e+01)
Module=/usr/java/jdk-9+181/lib/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so
Module_base_address=00007F822A52F000
Target=2_90_20170915_6 (Linux 4.12.12-300.fc26.x86_64)
CPU=amd64 (8 logical CPUs) (0x3dfa5d000 RAM)
----------- Stack Backtrace -----------
(0x00007F822A5EBA20 [libj9vm29.so+0xbca20])
(0x00007F821BF2D7C4 [libjclse9_29.so+0x457c4])
(0x00007F821BF2DA5B [libjclse9_29.so+0x45a5b])
(0x00007F821BF347C0 [libjclse9_29.so+0x4c7c0])
(0x00007F8229F0B7B4 [libffi29.so+0x67b4])
ffi_call+0x1b8 (0x00007F8229F09EB8 [libffi29.so+0x4eb8])
(0x00007F822A554A9B [libj9vm29.so+0x25a9b])
(0x00007F822A541B3B [libj9vm29.so+0x12b3b])
(0x00007F822A5F82C2 [libj9vm29.so+0xc92c2])
---------------------------------------
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "gpf", detail "" at 2017/09/21 15:46:12 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using '/path/to/openjfx/rt/core.20170921.154612.4490.0001.dmp' in response to an event
JVMPORT030W /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern setting "|/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %e" specifies that the core dump is to be piped to an external program.  Attempting to rename either core or core.4526.

JVMDUMP012E Error in System dump: The core file created by child process with pid = 4526 was not found. Expected to find core file with name "/path/to/openjfx/rt/core.4526"
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/path/to/openjfx/rt/javacore.20170921.154612.4490.0002.txt' in response to an event
```

Does anybody have any suggestions for how I can get OpenJFX to build with J9?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you crosspost a link to this question to the [openjfx-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev).

Comment: Java 9 has tightened much up on security, and something here is trying to use reflection to peek inside where Oracle do not want them to.   This is a good thing even though it is a pain now.

Comment: Also try with OpenJDK 9 - you might find you see the same error.

Comment: Which version of gradle are you using?  If you can post details of your environment in https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues/110 hopefully we get to the bottom of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenJ9 team have reproduced the crash and are investigating the cause - see https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues/110.

Quoting from that issue:

> It fails when calling JVM_GetSystemPackage_Impl with "com/ibm/lang/management/internal/"
>
> It ends up calling getModuleJRTURL () with a NULL moduleName. I'm investigating why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

You are using openjdk9-openj9, and segmentation fault is likely an issue with OpenJ9. Better to report an issue here: https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues
so that OpenJ9 developers can look at it and help you out.